# An Example of Galois Group

Tags: galois-theory

I wish to classify the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\pi/4})/\mathbb{Q}$. Let me denote the eighth root of unity as $\epsilon$. I see that $1, \epsilon, \epsilon^2, \epsilon^3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, although I do not know how to rigorously prove this (can anyone show me?). Since $\{\epsilon, \epsilon^2, \epsilon^3\}$ are linearly independent does that mean $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i\pi/4}):\mathbb{Q}] = 8$, or is it some other value (if it is please explain why)? Are my observations correct so far?

Comment: Don't You want to consider an eighth root of unity as $(e^{i\pi/4})^4=-1$?

Comment: Or, if you really want to talk about a fourth root of unity, you should rather write $e^{2i\pi/4}$, or use its little nickname $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $\epsilon = e^{\pi i\over 4}$ is $x^4 + 1 = 0$. To see this, note that it is easy to see from Euler's formula that $x^4 = e^{i \pi} = -1$. On the other hand, $x^4+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ (Apply Eisenstein to $(x+1)^4+1$).

Now, $1,\epsilon, \epsilon^2,\epsilon^3$  are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ , for if not then any linear combination of theirs is a cubic polynomial with rational coefficients in $\epsilon$. If it equaled zero, then there is a polynomial of degree $4$ and degree less than $3$ which $\epsilon$ satisfies. So $\epsilon$ must satisfy the $\gcd$ of these polynomials. What can that $\gcd$ be? Get a contradiction.

---

From the fact that the degree of the minimal polynomial equals the degree of the extension, we get that $[\mathbb Q(\epsilon) : \mathbb Q] = 4$. (Hint : Suppose you did not know this fact : we know that $1,\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\epsilon^3$ are l.i. : use $\epsilon^4 = -1$ to reduce any polynomial in $\epsilon$ to one involving only these four powers. That will show the spanning nature of these numbers and therefore the result as well.)

---

The Galois group of this extension is $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$. To see this, we look at a specific member of the automorphism , the one sending $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon^3$.

What does that mean? Well, the automorphism is multiplicative and additive. So, it sends $$\epsilon^2 = \epsilon \times \epsilon \to \epsilon^3 \times \epsilon^3 = \epsilon^6 = -\epsilon^2 \\
\epsilon^3 \to \epsilon^9 = \epsilon \\
\epsilon^{-1} \to (\epsilon^3)^{-1} = \epsilon^{-3} \\
\epsilon^{-3} \to \epsilon^{-9} = -\epsilon$$

So basically, any element of the form $a+b\epsilon + c \epsilon^2 + d \epsilon^3$ (which is the general form of an element of this extension) goes to $a + b\epsilon^3 - c \epsilon^2 + d \epsilon$.

This has order $2$, as can be seen easily.

See, the roots of $x^4+1 = 0$ are $\epsilon, - \epsilon , i \epsilon , -i\epsilon$. So the four automorphisms are taking $\epsilon$ to each of those above (one of them is secretly $\epsilon^3$, so we have already seen that above. Which one?). One can check this.

Comment: @ancientmathematician and астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг  Thank you very much. Is the Galois group the splitting field of $x^4 - 1 = (x - e^{i\pi/4})(x - e^{-i\pi/4})(x - e^{i3\pi/4})(x - e^{-i3\pi/4})$?

Comment: indeed it is @user758469

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome! If you liked my answer, you can call me to your other questions using this link.

Comment: so this will be isomorphic to Klein Four group? My reason: Four automorphisms, three of which have order two.

Comment: so isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Quick question, the automorphism you talked about earlier that sends $\epsilon \to \epsilon^3$, how is it defined exactly? Does it send $\epsilon^{-1} \to \epsilon^{-3}$, $\epsilon^{3} \to \epsilon$ and $\epsilon^{-3} \to \epsilon^{-1}$?

Comment: I have made an error. You were correct initially, it seems that the group of automorphisms is the Klein group. Also I have expanded upon the definition in my answer.

Comment: I cannot be apologetic enough. I shall delete all comments involving the mistake. Your definition is correct, I have said something more anyway.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful!

Comment: you are welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107361/discussion-between-user758469-and----).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon:=e^{i\pi/4}$ be the primitive 8th root of unity.

Then $\epsilon$ is an $8$-th root but not a $4$-th root, so is a root of $(X^8 -1)/(X^4-1)$.

That is $\epsilon$ is a root of $X^4 +1$.

Now for $X$ real $X^4+1>1$; so $X^4+1$  has no real roots, and so no rational roots.

Hence if it factorises it factorises in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ then it factorises as the product of two rational quadratics. However in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ we  have $X^4+1=(X^2 +\sqrt{2}X+1)(X^2-\sqrt{2}X+1)$, and as these factors are not rational we see that $X^4+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

We therefore have that $1, \epsilon,\epsilon^2,\epsilon^3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.